# why browser is saying Ckeditor is undefined after I aggregated js files in drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, ckeditor

why the Ckeditor is undefined after I aggregated js files in drupal 7?
ckeditor was working for admin and editor role content add/edit but after I aggregated css & js files, now it is giving ckeditor is undefined for editor role

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. It was admin theme permission issue for the editor role.